# Função JavaScript para uso genérico

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função em javascript simples que faz o calculo do valor de um campo multiplicado pelo valor de outro e insere em um terceiro. Abaixo o código:

```
function multiplica() {
    var quantidade = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tab1quantidade").value);
    var aux = document.getElementById("tab1valor");
    var valor = parseFloat(aux.options[aux.selectedIndex].value);
    document.getElementById("tab1total").value = parseFloat(quantidade * valor).toFixed(2); 
}
```

Os campos estão da seguinte forma:

```
<td class="col-md-3">
  <input type="number" min="0" max="10" step="1" class="form-control text-center" name="bulletin['tab6quantidade']" id="tab6quantidade" value="0" onChange="multiplica();">
</td>
```

Eu preciso usar essa mesma função para outros campos porém com IDs diferentes. Tenho que passar o ID do campo como parâmetro mas não sei como informar o dado corretamente.

Comment: Mostra mais HTML e as relações entre as contas que queres fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi bem, seria isto:

```
function multiplica(tabName) {
    var quantidade = parseFloat(document.getElementById(tabName + "quantidade").value);
    var aux = document.getElementById(tabName + "valor");
    var valor = parseFloat(aux.value);
    document.getElementById(tabName + "total").value = (quantidade * valor).toFixed(2); 
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
multiplica('tab1');
```